# If $\alpha$ is algebraic over a Field, find a nonzero polynomial such that $q(\alpha^2) = 0$

Tags: field-theory

Let $\alpha$ be algebraic over a field, $F$, with minimal polynomial $p(t) = t^3+t+1$. 
Find a nonzero polynomial $q(t) \in F[t]$ such that $q(\alpha^2) = 0$.

Now, I get that $\alpha^3 = -\alpha - 1$
and that $\alpha^4 = -\alpha^2-\alpha$
and that $\alpha^5 = -\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1$ and so on - but I don't know how to use this information to get the answer?

Answer (score 4):

We know that $\alpha^{3}+\alpha+1=0$, hence also $$(\alpha^{3}+\alpha+1)^{2}=\alpha^{6}+2\alpha^{4}+2\alpha^{3}+\alpha^{2}+2\alpha+1=0.$$
As $2\alpha^{3}+2\alpha+1=2(\alpha^{3}+\alpha+1)-1=-1$, this implies that
$$\alpha^{6}+2\alpha^{4}+\alpha^{2}-1=0.$$
So $\alpha^{2}$ is a root of the polynomial $q(t)=t^{3}+2t^{2}+t-1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, @studiosus !!

Answer (score 4):

Gather the even and odd powers of $t$ in the minumum polynomial of $\alpha$:
$$\alpha^3 + \alpha = 1.$$
Now square both sides to obtain
$$\alpha^6 + 2 \alpha^4 + \alpha^2 = 1.$$
Therefore, $\alpha^2$ is a root of $q(t) = t^3 + 2 t^2 + t - 1$.

Comment: +1: This answer gives a procedure  to get a  polynomial satisfied by $\alpha^2$ using the minimal polynomial of any $\alpha$.